# Find/replace Highlight replaced words Netbeans/Java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Any ideas how to highlight the replaced words in JTextpane. I tried many options but the closest I get is that only the first occurrence of the word is highlighted, the other highlights are shifted. I used method below. I already used it for finding and highlighting words. So I thought if I could modify it a bit, I could also use it also for find and replace method. Thanks.

```
Highlighter.HighlightPainter PaintChange = new PaintFind(Color.yellow);

    try {
            Highlighter color = textpane.getHighlighter();
            String find = FieldFind.getText();
            String replace = FieldReplace.getText();
            Document doc = textpane.getDocument();
            String text = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());
            int pos = 0;
            int counter = 0;

            while((pos=text.toUpperCase().indexOf(find.toUpperCase(), pos))>=0) {

                int i = textpane.getText().indexOf(find, 0);
                textpane.select(i, i+find.length());
                text.replaceSelection(FieldReplace.getText());

                color.addHighlight(pos, pos+replace.length(), PaintFind);
                pos += find.length();

                counter++;
            }
            status.setText("Nuber of changed words: " + " " + Integer.toString(counter));

        } catch(Exception e){

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> the closest I get is that only the first occurrence of the word is highlighted, the other highlights are shifted

```
int i = textpane.getText().indexOf(find, 0);
```

Don't use `textPane()getText()`. This will include "\r\n" in the text. However, the Document only has "\n" so then index used for the highlighting will be off by one for each additional line.

You already have the text from the Dcoument using:

```
String text = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());
```

so just do the searching on the "text" variable.

Check out [Text and New Lines](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/text-and-new-lines/) for more detailed information.

Edit:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class FindSSCCE extends JPanel
{
    JTextField find = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField replace = new JTextField(10);
    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
    Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter( Color.cyan );

    public FindSSCCE()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        JPanel north = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 2) );
        north.add( new JLabel("Find") );
        north.add( find );
        north.add( new JLabel("Replace") );
        north.add( replace );
        add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        add(new JScrollPane(textPane));

        JButton findReplace = new JButton("Find and Replace");
        add(findReplace, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        findReplace.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try
                {
                    String findText = find.getText();
                    int findLength = findText.length();
                    String replaceText = replace.getText();
                    int replaceLength = replaceText.length();

                    Document doc = textPane.getDocument();
                    String text = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());
                    int offset = 0;

                    while ((offset = text.indexOf(findText, offset)) != -1)
                    {
                        textPane.select(offset, offset + findLength);
                        textPane.replaceSelection( replaceText );

                        textPane.getHighlighter().addHighlight(offset, offset + replaceLength, painter);
                        offset += replaceLength;
                        text = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());
                    }
                }
                catch(BadLocationException ble) {}
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FindSSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new FindSSCCE() );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note that this is not a very efficient solution because you need to get the text from the Document every time a change is made to make sure the offsets when searching the text string are in sync with the text in the Document.

Edit2:

A more efficient find/replace algorithm that uses the initial text string from the Document:

```
    findReplace.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            try
            {
                textPane.getHighlighter().removeAllHighlights();
                String findText = find.getText();
                int findLength = findText.length();
                String replaceText = replace.getText();
                int replaceLength = replaceText.length();

                Document doc = textPane.getDocument();
                String text = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());
                int count = 0;
                int offset = 0;

                while ((offset = text.indexOf(findText, offset)) != -1)
                {
                    int replaceOffset = offset + ((replaceLength - findLength) * count);
                    textPane.select(replaceOffset, replaceOffset + findLength);
                    textPane.replaceSelection( replaceText );

                    textPane.getHighlighter().addHighlight(replaceOffset, replaceOffset + replaceLength, painter);
                    offset += replaceLength;
                    //text = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());
                    count++;
                }
            }
            catch(BadLocationException ble) {}
        }
    });
```

Comment: If I put "text" variable instead of textpane.getText() only the first word is replaced and highlighted. I think the main thing is the pos variable that gets increased inside while loop. I tried numerous options but no success. And did not quite understand "do the searching on the text variable". If you could  explain that a bit ? Thanks

Comment: What I meant was you can't use textPane.getText() to do the indexOf(...) search because your offsets will be wrong for the reason I explained in the `Text and New Lines` link. So you need to search the text variable which needs to be refreshed in the loop every time you do a replacement See edit..