# How do I highlight the words that replaced the selected words?

Tags: java, swing, highlight, jtextpane

This code  replaces the selected words with the new ones like this:

```
String search = jTextField1.getText();
String replaced = jTextPane.getText().replace(search, jTextField2.getText());
jTextPane.setText(replaced);
```

What is the easiest way to set the backgrounds of the new words to yellow?

Comment: two questions 1. why, 2, why not to search in Document, I'm sure that Oracle tutorial - how to use TextComponents contains working code example about search and highlight matches in Document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use attributes:

```
Simple AttributeSet changed = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setForeground(changed, Color.RED);
StyleConstants.setBackground(changed, Color.YELLOW);

//  Change attributes on some text

StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
doc.setCharacterAttributes(20, 4, changed, false);
```

For find/replace logic check out: [Find/Replace, Highlight Words](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29450075/131872). You would modify the highlighting code to use the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void changeAllActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        int j = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int index = 0;
        String search = jTextField1.getText();
        String replaced = jTextPane.getText().replace(search, jTextField2.getText());
        jTextPane.setText(replaced); 
        String newtext = jTextField2.getText();

        try{
            if(!jTextField2.getText().isEmpty()){
                while(i != -1){
                        i = jTextPane.getText().indexOf(newtext, j);
                    if(i == -1)
                        break;
                    if(evt.getSource() == changeAll|| evt.getSource() == changeAllButton){
                        jTextPane.select(i, i + newtext.length());   
                    }
                    Color c = Color.YELLOW;
                    Style s = jTextPane.addStyle("TextBackground", null);
                    StyleConstants.setBackground(s, c);
                    StyledDocument d = jTextPane.getStyledDocument();
                    d.setCharacterAttributes(jTextPane.getSelectionStart(), jTextPane.getSelectionEnd() - jTextPane.getSelectionStart(), jTextPane.getStyle("TextBackground"), false);
                    j = i + search.length();
                    index++;
                }
                if (index > 0){
                    jTextPane.grabFocus();
                    jTextPane.setCaretPosition(jTextPane.getText().indexOf(newtext, 0) );
                } 
        } catch (Exception e){
            jLabel.setText("error");
            System.err.print(e);
}
```

Comment: `What is the easiest way to set the backgrounds of the new words to yellow?` - this solution doesn't satisfy that requirement. This will change the background off "all" the words in the text pane. For example If you change "0" to "1" in the above code snippet. All the "-1" values would be highlighted even though they were not changed. Also, this code will not work on Windows machines for the reason I provided in the link found in my answer.

Comment: @lol, what do you mean it works in your case? Did you even try what I suggested?. Copy the above code into your text pane and then replace "0" with "1". The "1" of the "-1" should NOT be highlighted because your find/replace logic did not change that value.